# How to use GCS bucket as workflow file source for Oozie in Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oozie, google-cloud-dataproc, oozie-workflow

We're migrating our EMR cluster to Dataproc, and we're relying on Oozie to run our workflows. The first challenges is how to load the `workflow.xml` from Cloud Storage bucket. We used to do it using S3:

```
oozie.coord.application.path=s3://my_workflow/workflows/daily
```

Trying to use same approach on GCS does not work at all

```
oozie.coord.application.path=gs://my_workflow/workflows/daily
```

When I try to run the Oozie job, I got this error:

```
gs URI scheme not supported
```

Do I have to manually configure the scheme on Oozie? I'm using [Dataproc initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/oozie) to deploy Oozie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your problem. Seems Oozie init action doesn't support loading workflow.xml from GCS yet. I think you can file a bug for the init action, but for now you might have to put the file in HDFS.

Regarding the fix, it needs:

1) In `/etc/oozie/conf/oozie-site.xml`, add

```
<property>
  <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.supported.filesystems</name>     
   <value>hdfs,gs</value>
   <decscription>...</decscription>
</property>
```

2) In `/etc/oozie/conf/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml`, add

```
<property>
  <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl</name>
  <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS</value>
  <description>The AbstractFileSystem for gs: uris.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>
    Whether to use a service account for GCS authorization.
    Setting this property to `false` will disable use of service accounts for
    authentication.
  </description>
</property>
```

3) Copy `gcs-connector.jar` from `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/` to `/usr/lib/oozie/lib`.

4) Restart Ooozie service with

```
sudo systemctl restart oozie.service
```